# How to use Jmeter for UI performance testing?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I would like to use Jmeter for UI performance testing.
How to use Jmeter for UI performance testing?
How can I get the loading time of the HTML elements?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As per [JMeter project](http://jmeter.apache.org/) main page:

> **JMeter is not a browser**, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages. **Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does** (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

So the only way of testing UI using JMeter is going for [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler/) which provides integration with [Selenium](https://selenium.dev/) browser automation framework.

WebDriver Sampler can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

Comment: I don't really see the point of doing this in Jmeter. You won't be able to create much load if every single Jmeter user needs to create and control a whole Browser instance (each one using a significant amount of memory and CPU).

Answer (score 1):

Just add the ELK RUM Agent to your Dev and Functional test environments.  Pull all of the w3c timings there.   Whether the test is being run manually or automgically, so long as a browser is involved that runs JavaScript you will receive the w3c navtiming metrics

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about applying load at your system back-end and running a parallel UI load test like Dmitri suggested? This might just help you to achieve what you need.

We use webpagetest.org in combination with our load test which allows us to record videos and compare it with previous release.

Comment: I cannot access my web application without VPN so webpagetest.org didn't work for my case. 
I thought about Dmitro suggested but I don't really see the point of doing this in Jmeter. You won't be able to create much load if every single Jmeter user needs to create and control a whole Browser instance (each one using a significant amount of memory and CPU).

Comment: I don't think I was clear. You run 2 tests, 1) once regular load test against your back-end and 2) either run UI test using JMeter selenium or access the UI manually to see the impact. Blazemeter Taurus allows you to start two tests in parallel see: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-working-multiple-jmeter-tests/